# Double to `unsigned long long` causes memory (stack?) corruption

Tags: c++, casting, visual-studio-2012, unsigned-long-long-int

What is wrong with the following code (crashes):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::string str, unsigned long long val)
{
    std::cout<< str<< " "<< val<< std::endl; // Crashes if commented as well
}

int main()
{
    double d = 30.0;
    foo("abc", d);
}
```

Visual Studio 2012/ Debug/ Win32

It works in x64 as well as if we change the `unsigned long long` to `long long` or even `unsigned long`

This code snippet crashes. In other scenarios the addresses of the function parameters are changed.

I suspect it has something to do with `_stol2` that converts the `double` to `unsigned long long`

Comment: Try it without the initial argument, the string.

Comment: Have you tested this MWE? There's nothing wrong with it visually, nothing wrong with it per the spec, nothing wrong with it with the multiple compilers that I have (but I don't have Visual Studio).

Comment: It works as expected on Visual studio 2010/debug/win32, I can't try it on 2012 at the moment but it should work on any compiler as far as I know.

Comment: The code generator and optimizer parts in VS2012 that deal with floating point values were drastically rewritten to support the new auto-vectorizing feature.  This has caused some breakage similar to this, the shoe fits.  First check if disabling whole-program optimization solves the problem.  Post your problem to connect.microsoft.com to get feedback from the people that can fix this bug.

Comment: MWE = Minimal Working Example. In other words, *Did you test this specific code?* If you did, it's a very nice short and simple example to submit to Microsoft as a bug. (And if it does break, it most certainly is a bug.)

Comment: @DavidHammen, I did. I'll test it in a couple more build configurations and submit it. Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant. Whole-program optimization was off. Thanks.

Comment: [Submitted to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773581/casting-double-to-unsigned-long-long-causes-memory-stack-corruption)

Comment: @Albert - Please add your own answer saying "Submitted to Microsoft" and then select it as the best answer so this stops coming up in "unanswered questions".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Submitted to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773581/casting-double-to-unsigned-long-long-causes-memory-stack-corruption) as a bug (Accepted)